Understanding the Relationship Between Cross Product Components and Differential Forms on a Membrane
I am struggling with a differential geometry and vector calculus concept involving the relationship between the cross-product components and differential forms. The specific context is a response explaining how differential forms relate to vector calculus on the 2D surface of a manifold $ \partial M $, parameterized by variables $ u $ and $ w $.
The response starts by stating that the area element vector $ \vec{dA} $ on the surface is given by:
$$\vec{dA} = \vec{u} \times \vec{w} \tag{1}$$
Where $ \vec{u} $ and $ \vec{w} $ are vectors tangent to the surface at a point, and the wedge product $ \wedge $ in three-dimensional space corresponds to the cross product $\times$.(I would expect something like $\vec{dA} = \vec{du} \wedge \vec{dw}$)
The explanation further claims that the specific component of the cross product $ v_y w_z - v_z w_y $ is equivalent to the differential form $ dy \wedge dz $ when applied to vectors.
$$v_y w_z - v_z w_y = dy \wedge dz \tag{2}$$
I struggle to understand how this algebraic component of the cross product translates into the differential form $ dy \wedge dz $. Could someone clarify why this equivalence holds, particularly how the projection and orientation considerations of differential forms align with this component of the cross-product?

I don’t see what you do in that post. $dA$, when applied to two tangent ve tors, gives the signed area of the parallelogram they span: $dA(v,w)=\pm|v\times w|$. $dy\wedge dz(u,v)$ gives the signed area of the projection onto the $yz$-plane of the parallelogram spanned by $u$ and $v$. You might find some of my lectures, linked in my profile, helpful. Start with the complete version of #24 (3510), at the very bottom of the list.

@TedShifrin There are several aspects here that are unclear to me. First, the original author has used the notation $dA(v,w)=|v \times w|$, which I assumed to be equivalent to $\vec{dA} = \vec{du} \wedge \vec{dw}$. Why are the dimensionless variables $u$ and $w$ are treated as vectors? Additionally, while I have a basic understanding of what $\vec{dy} \wedge \vec{dz}$ represents, the expression $\vec{dy} \wedge \vec{dz}(u, w)$ remains unclear to me.

Puttting $\vec{}$ over every differential does not make the notation better. Let $u=u^x\partial_x+u^y\partial_y+u^z\partial_z$ and use the same notation for the vector $w,.$ Then, since $dy(\partial_y)=1,,dy(\partial_x)=0$ and so on,
$$
(dy\wedge dz)(u,w)=dy(u),dz(w)-dz(u),dy(w)=u^yw^z-u^zw^y,.
$$
This is the $x$-component of $u\times w,.$ Geometrically it is  the signed area of the parallelogram spanned by $u,w$ after being projected into the $(y,z)$-plane. @TedShifrin did you mean $dA(v,w)=\pm|v\times w|=dy\wedge dz(v,w),?$

No, @Kurt. There was a period and this was a new thought. Foad, no, no vectors.

@KurtG. , I believe your notation for $u$ and $w$ corresponds to what I would express as $\vec{u} \cdot \vec{\nabla}$. The need to introduce a new notation is unclear, but let's move forward. I am still puzzled by the terms $dy(\partial_y)$, $dy(\partial_x)$, $dy \wedge dz (u, w)$, $dy(u)$, $dz(u)$, $dy(w)$, and $dz(w)$.

Yes you can express that $u$ in the 19th century notation $\vec u\cdot\vec\nabla$ but this does not get you an inch closer to understand what this has to do with differential forms (your title). The algebraic expressions $dy(\partial_x)$ were introduced by Cartan who found an ingenious way of algebraizing vector calculus. I suggest that you drop your water wings now and swim. Ted Shifrin has given one source in his first comment where to learn that from.

One more thing you should keep in mind during that process: With Cartan's notation $df(u)$ is the directional derivative of the function $f$ in the direction of the vector $u,.$ This $df(u)$ coincides with the traditional $\vec u\cdot\vec\nabla f,.$ In particular, when $f$ is the coordinate function $y$ we have $dy(\partial_x)=0,.$

@KurtG. Could you kindly guide me to the lecture where Ted explains the notation for $dy(\partial_y)$? I have gone through his lectures, but they start from very basic concepts. It would take me a lot of time to reach the point where he defines these terms. I have been studying differential forms and have a vague understanding of the concept of multidimensional parallelograms, the wedge product, k-forms being integrated over k-dimensional manifolds, and the d exterior derivative operator. However, the notations are not helping me.

It took me just a few minutes to spot in Ted's video lecture #24 (3510) around 28' that this is what you are desperately looking for. Swim !
